# evaluating "long long int " in c

Tags: c, types

I need to make a user to type an `long long int` value in c and then evaluate this value example

```
long long int x = 1234567;
```

Then my evaluation needs to know the no. of elemente and digit at each position:

```
if(digit at 2nd position == 2)
{
do something;
}else{
 do something else;  
}
```

i had tried to convert it into an array but the problem is how do i get  the array size in advance when i dont know what a user types e.g one user might type 1234 some other might type 211212121212 ..

Comment: Why `long long`? Are you intending to handle arbitrarily long input ultimately?

Comment: Why not get the user input as string instead of integer?

Answer (score 1):

Print the `long long` to string with `sprintf` and then access the result by character.

Edit: if you use this approach you must also handle the negative value case.

Answer (score 1):

Convert number to string then use char at index 1 to check second number as follows:

```
char buf[20] = 0;
long long int number = 1234567LL;
snprintf(buf, 20, "%lld", number);
if (buf[1] == '2'){ // second char is 2
}
else{
}
```

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char* str(char* buf, long long int number)
{
    snprintf(buf, 21, "%lld", number);
    return buf;
}
int main(){
    long long int number = 1234567LL;
    char buf[20] = "";
    if(str(buf, number)[1] == '2'){ 
        printf("yes");
    }
    else{   
        printf("No");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically you could use ceil(log10()) to determine the # of digits, and/or a series of divisions/modulus/subtractions to determine the value of digits at X position.  Converting to a char array would be the easiest solution as mentioned (sprintf, itoa).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long int x = 1234567, i = x;

    while (i >= 100) i /= 10;
    printf("%lld\n", i % 10); /* prints the second digit */
    return 0;
}
```

Or put it in a function (works also for negatives):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* returns x digit or -1 */
int xdigit(long long int x, int pos)
{
    long long int e = pow(10, pos);

    if (x < 0) x = -x;
    if (x < e / 10) return -1;
    while (x >= e) x /= 10;
    return x % 10;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long int x = 1234567;

    printf("%s\n", xdigit(x, 2) == 2 ? "yes" : "no");
    return 0;
}
```

Must be compiled with `-lm` for `math.h`

Answer (score 0):

try using the folowing

double num = 23.345;

int intpart = (int)num;

double decpart = num - intpart;

printf("Num = %f, intpart = %d, decpart = %f\n", num, intpart, decpart);

now you have go the string from the decimal and integer part ... now proceed with the calculation by multiplying the decimal with 10 and save each in an array(say). 
**Alternatively**
you can also multiply the long decimal by 1 followed by the num of digits(say 5 for 5 points after decimal) & later can took them with an % opeartor.

Comment: You can also do the number to be converted in a string & reading the characters at every point .. & later converting it to the integer value ...

Comment: I cannot see how this answers the question, where does the double come from?

Comment: You can add long long .. it was just a example

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a long long int?  If the user inputs a number as a string,

```
char bignum[64];
int ii

fgets(bignum, sizeof(bignum), stdin);

for (ii = 0; ii < strlen(bignum); ++ii)
   printf("character %d is %c", ii, bignum[ii]);
```

Comment: Note that this will include the newline in `bignum` and print it as last character in the loop.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  Also if there is no newline character then the user has input 63 or more characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
please give me comment on the code    
Thy this code it uses division to find of number of digits
and uses division and modulo to digits at different positions
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
long long int i,x = 1234567;
int n=0;
i=x;    //make a copy of x
//block to find number of digit
for(;i!=0;i/=10)
{
n++;
}
printf("number of digits %d\n",n);
//Display digits
for(;x!=0;x/=10,n--)
{
printf("element at %d is %d\n",n,x%10);
}
}
```